# types of notifications in android gcm

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I' ve decided to use push notifications on GCM.What are the types of android push notifications?I'm talking about Google cloud messaging service for android.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you looked at the [official GCM page](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)? It contains all of the information you need. SO is here to help you with a specific problem related to programming, code. Not to do your research for you.

Comment: I looked and didnt found info about types of notifications there. I mean types like existing on win phone:toast notifications, tile notifications, and raw notifications. Are there such types in android gcm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no types. You can send whatever you wish, as long as it's not over 4096 bytes. Your Android application is responsible to receive the data and do with it whatever it wants (for example, it can display it as a notification, it can open the application that sent the notification at a specific activity, etc...). The is no predefined GUI for displaying GCM messages at the client side.

Comment: how can we create a notification that can't be cleared?